# Daily check in Trigger.io mobile application

Tags: trigger.io

I want to write a feature in my app that checks local data daily (at a specified time eg. 12:00pm), and alert if needed. Really, I want something kind of like [setTimeout()](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg) in Node.js.

Does Trigger.io's API give me a way to 'background' a small check, or fire an event at a specific time? Something via the OS,so that the app doesn't have to be running all the time?

I've searched through the API, but might be using the wrong terminology (as a non-mobile dev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something currently supported, mainly because its difficult to provide a consistent experience across Android and iOS.

A common solution to this kind of problem is to have the check performed on a remote server, then use a push notification to notify the user if required. (see http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/partners/parse.html#partner-parse)

The reason doing this on the device is difficult is that on iOS you cannot just run code in the background, it is possible to send a notification to the user at a specific time but this notification has to be set in advance.